# how can i make a filter quality score?

Tags: python

I couldn't make a function same as the example below I got one returned value only above 3 points

Filter quality is going to be determined according to the following formula:

```
q=((TP+TN)/(TP+TN+10*FP+FN))
```

Positive cases (P) are emails classified as spam by the filter, negative cases (N) are emails classified as normal email messages by the filter. FP is thus the number of emails incorrectly flagged as spam, FN is the number of spam emails getting through without being flagged.

It is important to note, that the `TP, FP, TN, FN` are frequencies (number of cases), not percentages.

Your filter will be evaluated on 3 different data sets. For each dataset, your filter may get 0 to 3 points:

```
   q       pts
<0, 0.3)    0
<0.3, 0.5)  1
<0.5, 0.7)  2
<0.7, 0.9)  2.5
<0.9, 1>    3
```

My Code So far:

```
def quality_score(TP, TN, FP, FN):
        q=(TP+TN//TP+TN+10*FP+FN)

        return q
```

Comment: what i read is : `TP  +  (TN/TP) + TN + 10*FP + FN`, you need to check your parenthesis

Comment: Please write if you have any concrete problem or error. Your existing code has one extremely simple mistake. And the rest of the implementation is more or less trivial.

Comment: Yes it is returning still the same one value ,how can i fix my function so it returns same as the example

Comment: i am not getting the question at all @MykhayloKopytonenko

Comment: i hoped some one explains it to me or showing me the way so i get it

Comment: your problem i think is, the parenthesis (as said earlier) and that you are computing an `int` (i guess?) that's why you probably get either 1 or 0.. to correct this is easy, and it will be better for you to do it by yourself knowing where to look.

Comment: I think, the author hasn't understood the task well enough. The function doesn't need to output 3 values. It first calculates the q value, and then gets the "quality points" from the "q - pts" table. For example, if q = 0.1, then pts = 0. If q = 0.4, then pts = 1, and so on.

Comment: Dividing int by int in Python 2.x gives int. To get float, convert one of the arguments to float: float(a) / b, and don't use //. In Python 3, the division will give float by default.

Comment: i am still not getting can you edit my post with the right code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the quality score table into a list with the range starting values. First, calculate the "q" value according to the formula. Then, look up the q value in the table to get the final quality points.

```
pointsTable = [
    (0, 0),
    (0.3, 1),
    (0.5, 2),
    (0.7, 2.5),
    (0.9, 3)
    ]

def calculate_quality_points(tp, tn, fp, fn):
    q = get_quality_score(tp, tn, fp, fn)
    return get_quality_points(q)

def get_quality_score(tp, tn, fp, fn):
    return float(tp + tn) / (tp + tn + 10 * fp + fn)

def get_quality_points(q):
    i = 0
    if q < 0 or q > 1:
        return -1
    for i in range(len(pointsTable) - 1):
        if q >= pointsTable[i][0] and q < pointsTable[i + 1][0]:
            return pointsTable[i][1]
    return pointsTable[len(pointsTable) - 1][1]
```

This code also checks if the q value is out of range [0, 1].

Usage:

```
print(calculate_quality_points(30, 20, 4, 3))
```